# React Router v4 Redirect Passing State Undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I have a private Route /something and I want it to be accessible only if logged in. I'm using Redirect with the state, but on destination location.state is undefined.

Here is the redirect:

```
<Redirect
  to={{
    pathname: "/login",
    state: { referrer: props.location }
  }}
/>
```

And in the destination, I' trying to access it, but I got undefined for the state.

```
this.props.location.state is undefined and I can't get referrer
```

I'm following [this example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow). Could be a bug?

Answer (score 1):

No its not a bug. Actually when you redirect from **page A to page B**, by the following way you will definitely get the `this.props.location.state`.

`<Redirect to={{pathname: "/b", state: { referrer: currentLocation }}} />`

Other than this, (direct open page A or coming from other than page B) you will get state `undefined`. Because in that scenario you are not passing the props `state` to page A.